# Schema Namespace UUID Issue New Components

Tags: cme, schema, web8.5, component

I am working on SDL Web 8.5 and only using the CME.  I have a Schema (`SchemaA`) with a `targetNamespace="uuid:xxx"`.  I can update existing Components based on `SchemaA` and save them.  Additionally, I can copy and paste these existing Components into other folders and work with the new copies. I can also preview these Components successfully with the Default Template.

However, if I create a new Component based off of `SchemaA` and try to save the Component (after filling out any mandatory fields) I get the following error:

> Unable to find uuid:xxx:Metadata.

This is stopping me from creating new Components based on this Schema.  Additionally, if I try to preview the Component before saving with the Default Template I get the following error:

> Unexpected namespace URI: uuid:yyy. Expecting: uuid:xxx.

For some reason, the UUIDs do not match up here. Furthermore, I have compared the **Source** tab of the new Components and the old ones, and they are identical.  I even tried copying the source from an existing (working) Component into a new one but I still could not save or preview.

Any ideas why newly created Components seem to be using the wrong namespace uuid?

Comment: Have you looked in the schema? Do you possibly have more than one SchemaA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was with how I was creating the new components.  When selecting a schema for a new component I was opening the schema dropdown and typing the letter "i" to get to the schema I wanted (instead of scrolling).  This was selecting a different schema first (since my desired schema was not the first "i" in the list) and loading the fields for it. Then I was opening the dropdown again and selecting my desired schema.  It turns out that the first schema that started with an "i" had a uuid of: "uuid:yyy" as seen in the preview error.

When creating a new component if I open the dropdown and scroll directly to the schema I want and click it without selecting any other schemas first, the issue does not present itself.

Comment: So basically if you choose one Schema first and then another, it doesn't update the Metadata to match the namespace of the latest Schema you selected? That would be a bug. Please report it if you haven't already :)